# Can someone explain the proportional hazards assumption for Cox Regression?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, assumptions, hazard

When cox regression says that proportional hazards are assumed, does that mean proportional hazards across all variables?

I've heard that it is only within two variables. But how? If the cox regression can fit more than 2 variables, should it not be assumed between all variables?

Comment: Where did you hear that this is only within two variables? The Cox model assumes that the hazard function $\lambda(t,X)$ can be written as $$\lambda(t,X) = \lambda_0(t) e^{X \cdot \beta}$$ This $X \cdot \beta$ can be a matrix product where $X$ represents many different variables.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I may have misunderstood a previous answer. So the correct answer is that all variables must have proportional hazards between themselves, correct?

Comment: Any two _combinations_ of predictor variables must have proportional hazards (PH). So if you fix all of the predictor variables except 1 at the same values between two cases, then PH must also hold for the 1 whose values you didn't fix.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Bookmarking.